# Android Studio Range Slider With Custom Thumb

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-drawable, android-slider

I have a RangeSlider in my android project I want to change my thumbs with one of my drawables. When i tried it with seekbar in my xml code this works ->

```
android:thumb="@drawable/my_drawable"
```

but it doesn't work with sliders or range slider. Is there any way to customise thumbs of range sliders?

Answer (score 0):

Try this programmitically through these methods :

for all values ->

```
public void setCustomThumbDrawable (Drawable drawable)

public void setCustomThumbDrawable (int drawableResId)
```

for specific values :

```
public void setCustomThumbDrawablesForValues (Drawable... drawables)

public void setCustomThumbDrawablesForValues (int... drawableResIds)
```

for example :

```
val rangeSlider = findViewById<RangeSlider>(R.id.movie_rating_range_slider)
    rangeSlider.setCustomThumbDrawable(R.drawable.ic_apple)
```